# Create SQLAlchemy session on event

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

If I want to use database while processing a request, I make a Dependency Injection like this:

```
@app.post("/sample_test")
async def sample_test(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(models.User.height).all()
```

But I cannot do it with events like this:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def sample_test(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(models.User.height).all()
```

because `starlette` events don't support Depends.

This is my `get_db()` function:

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

just like in FastAPI manual (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/).

How can I access `get_db()` inside my event function, so I can work with a Session?

I've tried:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def sample_test(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db = next(get_db())
    return db.query(models.User.height).all()
```

but it doesn't work.

I use MSSQL, if it's important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a dependency you can import the `SessionLocal` you've created as shown in the [FastAPI manual](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-sessionlocal-class) and use a [contextmanager](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#closing) to open and close this session:

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def sample_test():
    with SessionLocal() as db:
        return db.query(models.User.height).all()
```

Comment: ahh, so easy, yet so hard to come up to... thanks man!